# Debugging Javascript with remote reference in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

The following sample is supposed to create a chart using Chart.js. My HTML file (index.html) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ChartTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Sample Chart</h1>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript file (main.js) is

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

This works as expected when I run index.html locally outside of Visual Studio or on my website. But it doesn't work in Visual Studio. An error message tells me that the Chart class is undefined, and the title "Sample Chart" appears in the wrong font. Both problems are corrected by using local copies of the Chart.js file and the Bootstrap .css file. So it appears that Visual Studio (2017) has a problem using remote JS and CSS files. If anyone knows the cause and a solution to this problem I would be most grateful.

Comment: Is this file in a web application project? What is the URL in the address bar when you run it? You’re likely running in using a `file://` URL, which by default prevents loading of http references.

Comment: The project type was "Blank App (Universal Windows)". I've just tried using a "Black App - Web Context" project type, and it seems to be working correctly. (Although I can't see any difference between them.) So I'll remember to use that project type from now on. Thanks for the suggestion.